# Wordpress Loop Prob

Tags: categories

[image: This is my code snapshot]

im using this code to get the posts of the categories but the problem is this code is getting one less value than actual if there are total 5 post its getting 4 any when can plz check it .......... another thing is for first row it works properly but for second row it gets one less post

Comment: please post the code properly, or use pastebin.com to share the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now it seems like there is no query regarding the amount of posts to be shown.

Try adding this above your WHILE argument:

```
global $query_string;
query_posts( $query_string . '&posts_per_page=5' );
```

Comment: Consider using `query_posts( add_query_arg( array( 'posts_per_page' => 5 ), $query_string ) );`

Comment: and just a reminder that if you have sticky posts this can affect what get's returned eg you expect 2 posts but find you are getting 3.

Comment: i have just figured out the solution .. the elseif structure is not working in this code so i just removed the else and place another if instead of elseif ..... now its working properly